# How to get texts form a text file to AutoComplete c#/.net Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, autocomplete, io

i have created a login form and i am saving username or passwords to a text file useing `using System.IO` FileStream. And i want to use AutoComplete for username textbox or password textbox.

i want to get username or password in AutoComplete that i saved in text file so that i will not have to put the username ot password in textboxes.

It should show username or password in textbox to select like this (Click to see) http://i49.tinypic.com/rkuats.jpg  and  http://i46.tinypic.com/21edys1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What are you developing? If it's a web application, you can use jQuery UI to implement autocomplete for textboxes:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

If you are using WPF, you can do it similarly in C#:

```
 public Window1()
 {
     InitializeComponent();
     List<string> source = new List<string>{/*your source of strings*/};
     TextBoxName.ItemSource = source;
 }
```

Another method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Create the list to use as the custom source. 
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(new string[]
                {
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "October",
                    "November",
                    "December"
                });

// Create and initialize the text box.
var textBox = new TextBox
              {
                  AutoCompleteCustomSource = source,
                  AutoCompleteMode = 
                      AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend,
                  AutoCompleteSource =
                      AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource,
                  Location = new Point(20, 20),
                  Width = ClientRectangle.Width - 40,
                  Visible = true
              };

// Add the text box to the form.
Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Comment: reference sources: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/auto-complete-box-in-wpf-toolkit/

Comment: i am creating a sample login form in c# windows Form

Comment: I think you can do it similarly using the WPF method shown above

Comment: I have edited my answer, it's quoted from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i am not getting, i have already added textbox in my windows form.
i just want to read and add all texts from text file to AutoComplete

Comment: what i want is like this:- `foreach (string str in File.ReadAllLines("data.txt"))
                {
                    AutoComplete.Items.Add(str);
                }`

Comment: you can try storing the strings into an array first, and then `AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyStringArray` as shown above